# How to navigate thorugh a matrix without knowing its size

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a main class in java that receives a matrix[][], like: `

```
public main[] findBall(int[][] grid) {
        
    }
```

`
And then the user enters the imput:

```
[[1,1,1,-1,-1],[1,1,1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,-1],[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]]
```

I know it's a 5x5 but only because I saw what the user typed, how do I get the matrix size->(5x5) or any other size that they may type? or is there another way to navigate through it without knowing the size?

I tried nothing, I'm a beginner in Java so bear with me.

Comment: Hmmm... `grid.length`?

Comment: `grid.length` as @chptr-one suggested, and you can be extra-safe and iterate the nested arrays to ensure `grid[i].length` matches across the board.

Comment: Every question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an effort, it doesn't matter whether you're a beginner or experienced developer.  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

Understand matrices in Java more as an array of arrays. `grid` is an Array and will have a length, `grid.length`. Each entry of the grid is an Array with a length, so `grid[0].length` is the length of the first column. Assuming that every entry is of the same length, your matrix size will be `grid.length` x `grid[0].length`

Comment: Semantics, but most people would consider `grid[0]` to be the first _row_, particularly given how a 2D array literal would be read.

Answer (score 0):

If you are provided with an array and don't know its size, then you can also use its length with the Array property which is ("array-Variable").length and it will give you the length of the array. If you are working with a 2-D array then for the no. of rows you can use ("matrix-Variable").length and for the number of columns, you have to check the length of each row or 1st row by using ("matrix-Variable")[i].length where i can be either 0 or any number given the number is in range of the total number of rows.